# PHP Custom Contact form error

Tags: php

I am new in PHP programming. I have found one contact form tutorial, but it was not working. I don't know how can i solve this issue because i think there is no syntax error. I am using WAMP server to connect PHP.

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['contact_text'])) {
        $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];

        if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_text)) {
            $to = 'name@domain.com';
            $subject = 'Custom Contact Form';
            $body = $contact_name."\n".$contact_text;
            $headers ='From: '.$contact_email;

            if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                echo 'Your form has been submitted. We\'ll contact you shortly.';
                } else {
                echo 'There was an error';
            }

        }else {
            echo 'All fields are required.';
        }
}

?>
```

and here is the html code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
        Name: <br><input type ="text" name="contact_name"><br><br>
        Email address: <br><input type="text" name="contact_email"><br><br>
        Message:<br>
        <textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: elaborate "not working". Does SMTP account set correctly in php.ini ?

Comment: Remove the @ before mail as this is very very bad style. You probably just have no mail server configured and mail fails but you suppress it via @.

Comment: #1 I don't think the `mail();` function would work on WAMP and #2 as @Samuel said remove `@` from your `mail();` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble with the `mail()` function, it is most likely because you don't have a mail server running on your machine. I suggest using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It is pretty simple to use (it even comes with an example of using a Gmail account to send emails).

Also, you do not need to all of the `isset()` checks since you are also using `!empty()` right after because `empty()` checks if the variable is set and if it is "empty". A more detailed description can be found [here](https://www.php.net/empty).

Comment: Thanks mate. I have found the alternative script called sendmail which worked well on Wamp server.

Comment: No problem. I've never heard of this "sendmail" script before. If you have a link to it I'd like to see how it works.

Comment: yeah here it is - http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Comment: Oh I see, it's a separate executable that Windows runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
```

Sintax error, Remove @ char before mail word

Comment: Just for your information in case you didn't know (Could also be that I'm just reading it wrong) - `@` is perfectly valid syntax, although not very good practice. It's used to suppress errors caused by a specific function.